# Join Select Statement after on

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Is it possible to join on a part of a string that i split up?
I tried something:

```
SELECT param.par_name, 
   PARPAT.pp_pattern, 
   KOM.kom_name 
FROM   inv.inv_parpat PARPAT 
       INNER JOIN inv.inv_param PARAM 
               ON PARPAT.pp_par_id = PARAM.par_id 
       INNER JOIN inv.inv_komponente KOM 
               ON KOM.kom_id = (SELECT Substr(PARPAT.pp_pattern, 
                                       Instr(PARPAT.pp_pattern, ':') + 1 
                                       ) 
                                FROM   inv.inv_parpat) 
WHERE  PARPAT.pp_pattern LIKE '%ATA%';
```

This statement says:
Single row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Consider adding a Virtual Column to the INV.INV_PARPAT table, to hold that value of SUBSTR(PARPAT.PP_PATTERN,INSTR(PARPAT.PP_PATTERN, ':')+1). Then you can assign a meaningful name to the value, index it, and join on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join it to PARPAT based on the substring column. If you join with a subquery,the subquery should return only one value (like a max() or min() function will do). Else you can use a IN clause with a subquery. But remember, there are performance considerations while using IN. For your case, try the below query:

```
SELECT param.PAR_NAME,
       PARPAT.PP_PATTERN,
       KOM.KOM_NAME
  FROM INV.INV_PARPAT PARPAT
       INNER JOIN INV.INV_PARAM PARAM ON PARPAT.PP_PAR_ID = PARAM.PAR_ID
       INNER JOIN INV.INV_KOMPONENTE KOM on KOM.KOM_ID = (SUBSTR(PARPAT.PP_PATTERN,INSTR(PARPAT.PP_PATTERN, ':')+1))
 WHERE PARPAT.PP_PATTERN LIKE '%ATA%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use a sub query? You already have this table, why not use it? :

```
SELECT param.PAR_NAME,
       PARPAT.PP_PATTERN,
       KOM.KOM_NAME
  FROM INV.INV_PARPAT PARPAT
       INNER JOIN INV.INV_PARAM PARAM 
        ON PARPAT.PP_PAR_ID = PARAM.PAR_ID
       INNER JOIN INV.INV_KOMPONENTE KOM
        on KOM.KOM_ID = SUBSTR(PARPAT.PP_PATTERN,INSTR(PARPAT.PP_PATTERN, ':')+1)
WHERE PARPAT.PP_PATTERN LIKE '%ATA%';
```